# Given an object with a property that is an array of objects, how does one set a specific instance of said property in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, properties, nullreferenceexception

I have two objects: 'Table' and 'Record'. 'Table' has a property 'Items' that is an array of type 'Record[]'.

How do I set the 'Items' property of a specific instance of 'Table' (e.g., table.Items[0]) to a specific instance of 'Record' (e.g., first_record)?

I tried to code it as follows, but my code results in a "NullReferenceException was unhandled" error.

```
Record first_record = new Record();
first_record.Field1 = "r1f1";
first_record.Field2 = "r1f2";
first_record.Field3 = "r1f3";

Record second_record = new Record();
second_record.Field1 = "r2f1";
second_record.Field2 = "r2f2";
second_record.Field3 = "r2f3";

Table table = new Table();
table.Items[0] = first_record;
table.Items[1] = second_record;
```

Thank you

Comment: Please carefully read [MCVE] guidance to make your future questions better - in this case everyone knows that you didn't initialized array property, but in other cases lack of code that actually demonstrates the problem will likely earn you nice pile of downvotes.

Comment: @Abion47, I know it's clear I'm not a professional coder. But, I believe the code I provided in my question does actually demonstrate the problem. I put the corrected code in the answer I provided to my own question.

Comment: @Abion47, I should add that in my answer I did link to a similar question that helped me figure out my own problem. While my question may be trivial to experienced coders I don't think it's an exact duplicate of other questions.

Comment: Please read post as if it provided by some random person - you'll notice that there is no information about `Table` type (not even if it is class or struct, definitely no constructor), unrelated code for creating multiple `Record` instances with extra fields - basically no way to actually reproduce the problem. Also there is no *demonstrated* effort  of author performing research on particular exception. At that point you may wonder why post did not get a lot of downvotes for lack of information and was not closed as "missing minimal code".

Comment: @Abion47, thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackoverflow suggested a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127941/nullreferenceexception-on-array-property-of-object) that provided my answer. I failed to initialize the array. Here's the line I was missing:

```
table.Items = new Record[2];
```

Inserting that line into the code from my original question results in the following:

```
Record first_record = new Record();
first_record.Field1 = "r1f1";
first_record.Field2 = "r1f2";
first_record.Field3 = "r1f3";

Record second_record = new Record();
second_record.Field1 = "r2f1";
second_record.Field2 = "r2f2";
second_record.Field3 = "r2f3";

Table table = new Table();
table.Items = new Record[2];
table.Items[0] = first_record;
table.Items[1] = second_record;
```

That did the trick. Thank you Stackoverflow!